# Mysql performance: 1 query over 3 tables or 2 queries?

Tags: mysql, performance, caching, join

I need data from 3 different tables:

1. Catergory table
2. Scoretable 1
3. Scoretable 2

What is now better for the performance?

1. Make 3 seperated SELECT Queries
2. Make 2 queries and connect scoretable 1 and 2 and make a normal select query for the categories
3. Connect all 3 queries in 1?

Number 2:

```
SELECT scoretable1.category, scoretable1.score, scoretable2.score
FROM scoretable1, scoretable2
WHERE scoretable1.consultant = scoretable2.consultant 
AND scoretable2.consultant = '14' 
AND scoretable1.category = scoretable2.category
```

Thank you very much!

P.S. The category table is very small so I could export it also as a cache file as a serialized array? (Maybe the best way for this table)

Comment: Why don't you try both ways, and see which is faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that it is best to do it in one query. But i'm not absolutely sure. Maybe the [query analyser](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/query.html) can help you out here.

Answer (score 0):

the fastest would be an INNER JOIN from the category table to the two others, just try to do 1000 select within a program and check the time it takes with all different methods